# c++ set outputs many more elements than it contains

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, set, std

I have a very large set of strings for which I want to find the subset of unique strings and I am using the set container. The methods go out to a MySQL database, pull in a new group of strings and tries to add them to a set. I check the return from the insert to determine if the string was added (first occurrence) or it is already present.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "CDR3Sample.h"
#include "MySQLConnect.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    CDR3SetReturn ret;
    //CDR3Set is a typedef on set<string>
    CDR3Set total;

    try
    {
            MySQLConnect connection;
            cerr << "size of master " << connection.getMasterSize() << endl;

            SampleIDList list = connection.getSampleIDList();
            SampleIDList ids_seen;
            cerr << "size of raw ID list " << list.size() << endl;


            for (SampleIDListIterator it=list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
                    // We're going to skip it if the table doesn't exist or if the sample has already been processed
                if (connection.checkTable(*it) && find(ids_seen.begin(), ids_seen.end(), *it)!=list.end()) {
            CDR3Sample s(*it, connection);
            int valid_number = 0;
            for (CDR3SetIterator sit=s.begin(); sit != s.end(); sit++) {
                ret = total.insert(*sit);
                if (ret.second) {
                    valid_number++;
                }
            }
            cout << *it << " " << s.getLength() << " " << valid_number << " " << total.size() << endl;
            ids_seen.push_back(*it);
                } else {
                    cerr << *it << " table not found" << endl;
                }
            }
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
            // Need to put code here to save state of calculation
        std::cerr << "Exception thrown by MySQLConnect " << i << std::endl;

        exit(-1);
    }

    // Need to put code here to save state of calculation
    cerr << "size of total " << total.size() << endl;
    ofstream ofs ("cdr3_tally.test", ifstream::out);
    int it_count=0;
    while (ofs.good()) {
        for (CDR3SetIterator it=total.begin(); it != total.end(); ++it) {
            cout << it_count << " " << *it  << endl;
            it_count++;
        }
    }
    ofs.close();
    cerr << "it_count " << it_count << endl;

    ofs_naive.close();


    return 0;
}
```

I'll leave the supporting code out for brevity, but I can provide it.

When it gets to the end, it has the correct number of entries:

```
size of master 9243
size of raw ID list 1
~MySQLConnect
size of total 372
```

But the loop that write out the set just keeps going and going for millions of lines. If I use sort -u on the output, it has the correct number of entries.

I am stumped. The code looks OK to me. It's not the complicated.

Can anyone see something that I have done wrong? Should I make a formal class out of CDR3Set instead of a typdef?

I am using g++ on ubuntu

> $ g++ -v
>   Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
>   Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
>   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Not sure if this has anything todo with it but CDR3SetIterator it=total.begin(); is bad practice you should make the iterator outside of the loops.

Comment: I think `while (ofs.good())` you must change to `if (ofs.good())`

Comment: I just changed the output to

Comment: Changing 'while' to 'if' and taking the iterator definition out of the loop solved the problem. Thanks. I also found a construct std::ostream_iterator< double > output( cout, " " );

   cout << "doubleSet contains: ";
   std::copy( doubleSet.begin(), doubleSet.end(), output ); that worked

Comment: @Camron_Godbout Why is that (iterators should not be created in the `for` header)?

Comment: @dlf I was taught to always create the iterator outside of loops then use it. When he put it inside the top 2 for loops that's a little gray area but I was taught never instantiate a new iterator in a loop like that because crazy shenanigans can happen. Had a few peers do it on vectors full of classes and seg fault errors wtf?, pretty mysterious.

Comment: @Camron_Godbout Well; I have to say I've never heard that before and can't think of why it would be a problem. `for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(): ++it)` is an idiom I use all the time (or at least did before the range-based `for` was implemented) and it's never caused me any trouble... (just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/189055/3549027) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cout` for loop is enclosed in `while(ofs.good())`. Nothing inside the for loop will ever make it bad, so it keeps looping over the set and printing everything again and again.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't catch that.